# Orthogonal hull algorithm

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull, orthogonal

I am trying to find a way to determine the [rectilinear polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon) from a set of integer points (indicated by the red dots in the pictures below). The image below shows what I would like to achieve:

**1.**

[image]

I need only the minimal set of points that define the boundary of the rectilinear polygon. Most hull algorithms I can find do not satisfy the orthogonal nature of this problem, such as the [gift-wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm), which produce the following result (which is **not** what I want)...

**2.**

[image]

How can I get the set of points that defines the boundary shown in image **1.**?

**Updated:**

Figure 1. is no longer refereed to as convex..

Comment: Could you please clarify which orthogonal polygons are considered convex for you? Right now it is not completely clear what to search for.

Comment: Is the term `orthographic convex hull` standard? Given that the hull is not convex even considering only directions defined by the orthogonal basis (i.e., outside the lattice there are points not in the set), you might just need to find the magic keyword. Also: are you always in 2-d?

Comment: Your example on fig1. isn't convex

Comment: @Leo I'm always in 2d. Rectilinear polygon might be a better term but I am still finding it hard to find satisfactory results.

Comment: Your question is missing essential information: are you working with a binary image or a list of 2D points (presumably having integer coordinates) ?

Comment: If we remove one of the rightest points - how you hull would look like? With spike?

Comment: @MBo Yes, with a spike.

Comment: All the points that are not used to construct the hull have in common that they are surround by 8 points. This could be the basis of the selection of the next point.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [definition from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull), it is rather easy to create a fast algorithm.

1. Start constructing upper hull from the leftmost point (uppermost among such if there are many). Add this point to a list.
2. Find the next point: among all the points with both coordinates strictly greater than of the current point, choose the one with minimal *x* coordinate. Add this point to your list and continue from it.
3. Continue adding points in step 2 as long as you can.
4. Repeat the same from the rightmost point (uppermost among such), but going to the left. I.e. each time choose the next point with greater *y*, less *x*, and difference in *x* must be minimal.
5. Merge the two lists you got from steps 3 and 4, you got upper hull.
6. Do the same steps 1-5 for lower hull analogously.
7. Merge the upper and lower hulls found at steps 5 and 6.

In order to find the next point quickly, just sort your points by *x* coordinate. For example, when building the very first right-up chain, you sort by *x* increasing. Then iterate over all points. For each point check if its *y* coordinate is greater than the current value. If yes, add the point to the list and make it current.

Overall complexity would be *O(N log N)* for sorting.

EDIT: The description above only shows how to trace the main vertices of the hull. If you want to have a full rectilinear polygon (with line segments between consecutive points), then you have to add an additional point to your chain each time you find next point. For example, when building the right-up chain, if you find a point *(x2, y2)* from the current point *(x1, y1)*, you have to add *(x2, y1)* and *(x2, y2)* to the current chain list (in this order).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to compute is the Rectilinear Convex Hull (or Orthogonal Convex Hull) of the set of points. The rectilinear convex hull is an ortho-convex shape, that is, the intersection of the shape with any horizontal or vertical line results in an empty set, a point, or a line segment.

The vertices of the rectilinear convex hull are the set of maximal points under vector dominance. The rectilinear convex hull can then be computed in optimal O(n log n) time. A very simple algorithm is presented in [Preparata's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387961313) on Computational Geometry (see the section 4.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard algorithm for this but it doesn't seem too complicated to define:

Assuming each point in the grid has at least 2 neighbors (or else there's no solution)

1. p = a point with only two neighbors.
2. while p isn't null

   2a. Mark p as visited

   2b. next = the unmarked neighbor that has the least amount of neighbors

   2c. next.parent = p

   2d. p = next

done