# Can I get help on a Rectilinear Polygon Hull Algorithm (in javascript if possible)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, polygon

Edited title and here to reflect my question better.
My first description didn't get answers of the kind I was looking for and I didn't know there was a fancy name for this kind of shape I'm trying to make.
I studied Graham Scan algorithms but they don't completely cover the answer I'm looking for either, as they tend to "cut corners" if the shape becomes strange say.

Based on some articles I found, I'd started writing my own algorithm and it works a lot of the cases to be sure but I keep coming into problems I cant seem to completely stamp out, I believe the problem might be where I'm trying to calculate each of the corners.

This is the logic of my algorithm -

1st = Find the corners, top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left

2nd = Enter a while loop, travelling towards a target, starting from top-left travelling to top-right then to bottom right to bottom left and back to top left.

3rd = in each iteration of this while loop, we find the neighbours of each tile if they exist in this list, and choose the next tile to travel to, based on which comes first in an order decided by priority.

Priority explained, if the priority is to get to the top right corner, we take our time by first trying to travel to the left, then up, right and down but ONLY if a tile in this direction exists and ONLY if this tile isn't the previous tile we were standing at.
After we arrive at the top right corner, we shift the priority list making the first priority become the last. So

priority = [left, up, right, down]

becomes

priority = [up, right, down, left]

In the majority of cases my code IS performing as expected, like the logic seems sound, but there are a few anomaly moments where it doesn't seem to pick the right tile based on the priority I'm giving it and instead it wanders about the whole array. If anyone can help me where I'm making a mistake I'd appreciate this.

Heres my current algorithm code >

```
            draw_hull = function() {
                var list = [],
                    coordinates = [],
                    original_list = this.territory,
                    _x = 0, // coords are in arrays, [x,y] style.
                    _y = 1; // this is just for readers readability



                // make list to be looped through, for each tile I deliberately added 4,
                //it'll look more readable in the final product.
                for (var i = 0; i < original_list.length; i++) {
                    list.push( [ (original_list[i][_x] * 32) + 8,   (original_list[i][_y] * 32) + 8 ] );
                    list.push( [ (original_list[i][_x] * 32) + 24,  (original_list[i][_y] * 32) + 8 ] );
                    list.push( [ (original_list[i][_x] * 32) + 24,  (original_list[i][_y] * 32) + 24    ] );
                    list.push( [ (original_list[i][_x] * 32) + 8,   (original_list[i][_y] * 32) + 24    ] );
                }

                // find corners
                var topleft = 0, topright = 0, bottomright = 0, bottomleft = 0, hull = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var x = list[i][_x];
                    var y = list[i][1];

                    if (x <= list[topleft][_x] && y <= list[topleft][_y]) topleft = i;
                    if (x >= list[topright][_x] && y <= list[topright][_y]) topright = i;
                    if (x >= list[bottomright][_x] && y >= list[bottomright][_y]) bottomright = i;
                    if (x <= list[bottomleft][_x] && y >= list[bottomleft][_y]) bottomleft = i;
                }

                // start drawing paths from one corner to the next, repeating until a full loop has been made
                var priorities = ["l","u","r","d"], // travel the outline in this order, left up right down
                    current = topleft, // current tile
                    last = topleft; // last tile
                    target = [topright,bottomright,bottomleft,topleft],
                    target_iterator = 0, // target iterator so we know which corner we're striving towards
                    xx = 0, // an iterator to make sure this loop doesnt go on forever
                    done = false;

                while(!done) {
                    // add the current tile to our hull list.
                    hull.push(current);

                    var next = {},
                        cx = list[current][_x],
                        cy = list[current][_y];

                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        var x = list[i][_x], y = list[i][_y];
                        if (x === cx && y === cy -16) { next.up = i; continue; }
                        if (x === cx && y === cy +16) { next.down = i; continue; }
                        if (x === cx -16 && y === cy) { next.left = i; continue; }
                        if (x === cx +16 && y === cy) { next.right = i; continue; }
                    }

                    var i = 0, check = priorities;
                    for (var i = 0; i < priorities.length; i++) {
                        var check = priorities[i];

                        // skip this if next check doesnt exist, or is the tile we just came from
                        if (next[check] == null || next[check] == undefined|| next[check] === last) continue;

                        var visited = false;

                        for (var j = 1; j < hull.length; j++) {
                            if (hull[j] === next[check]) {
                                visited = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        if (visited) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    last = current;
                    current = next[check];

                    xcoords = list[current][_x];
                    ycoords = list[current][_y];
                    coordinates.push([xcoords,ycoords]);

                    if (current === target[target_iterator]) {
                        priorities.push(priorities.shift());
                        target_iterator++;
                        if (target_iterator === 4) break;
                    }

                    xx++;
                    if (xx > 50) {break; debugger;}
                }

                if (xx < 50) this.hull = coordinates;
            }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: I try to reformulate to check if i got your question right: you have an arbitrary list of points (which correspond to your starting shape); You want a function that, given the list of points, strokes / outlines them. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` with a `stroke()`. Further documentation is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

A simple drawing function could look like this: (or check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2skqLc7a/1/))

```
function drawShape(coords) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();

    for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            ctx.moveTo(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
        }
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

}
```

Comment: You have many redundant calls. After you do the first moveTo you do not need the other moveTo. Rather than do the line back to the start use ctx.closePath to create the closing line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've updated my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Oh and forgot, the lineTo should be in the forward direction  ctx.lineTo(coords[i ].x , coords[i ].y ); also if you want to scale shapes you are better off using ctx.scale(0.5,0.5) or ctx.setTransform(0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0)

Comment: And one last tip. (looking at your fiddle) When you create an array use the literal method `array = [];` and if you have many static object to add to the array `array = [{x : 10, y : 10}, {x : 20, y : 10}, ... etc ];` that will make the code more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily stroke an "unlimited" amount of corners, or vertices of a shape using moveTo() and lineTo(). Below is an example of how you could draw a triangle, but you could easily extend it by adding more path methods.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Filled triangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25,25); //moves 'pen' to coords
ctx.lineTo(105,25); //draws line from prior coords to new specified coords.
ctx.lineTo(25,105);
ctx.fill(); //fills in shape

// Stroked triangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(125,125);
ctx.lineTo(125,45);
ctx.lineTo(45,125);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke(); //strokes along path (i.e shape outline)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

This code can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes along with detailed advice on how to draw more complex shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, further studies, I found a name for the type of shape I'm trying to draw.
Its called an Rectilinear polygon.

[Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496421/orthogonal-hull-algorithm) already has an answer for this, was just hard to find.